# Check to see if directory has no files, but it may contain subfolders

Tags: c#

I need to check to see if a directory is empty. The problem is, I want to consider the directory empty if it contains a sub folder regardless of whether or not the sub folder contains files. I only care about files in the path I am looking at. This directory will be accessed across the network, which kind of complicates things a bit. What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [`Directory.EnumerateFiles(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458) method overload only returns files contained *directly* within the specified directory. It does not return any subdirectories or files contained therein.

```
bool isEmpty = !Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Any();
```

The advantage of `EnumerateFiles` over `GetFiles` is that the collection of files is enumerated on-demand, meaning that the query will succeed as soon as the first file is returned (thereby avoiding reading the rest of the files in the directory).

Comment: For info; Directory.EnumerateFiles(string) was added in .NET 4, so won't work in older versions of .NET.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps this:

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(path).Length == 0)...... ;
```